# Degree of the discriminant curve of conic bundle associated to a cubic threefold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians

Let $X\subset \mathbb P^4_{\mathbb C}$ be a smooth cubic hypersurface and $l_0\subset X$ a generic line. It is known that the resolution of indeterminacies of the projection $X\dashrightarrow \mathbb P^2$ with center $l_0$ yields an ordinary conic bundle $\widetilde X\rightarrow \mathbb P^2$. The discriminant curve of this conic bundle is a smooth quintic. I wanted to see that the degree is $5$ (not using the form of equation...) but it seems not to work and I do not know why:

we can see the base $\mathbb P^2$ embedded in $G(3,5)$ (the locus of $2$-planes containing $l_0$), with $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)\simeq \mathcal O_{G(3,5)}(1)_{|\mathbb P^2}$, and $\widetilde X\subset \mathbb P(\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2})$ given by the vanishing of a $q\in H^0(\mathbb P(\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2}),\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2})}(2)\otimes \pi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(k))$ (for some $k$). Then the discriminant curve has class $c_1(Sym^2\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2}(k))$ but since $rank(Sym^2\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2})=6$ and $c_1(Sym^2\mathcal E_{3|\mathbb P^2})=4c_1(\mathcal E_3)_{|\mathbb P^2}$, I cannot see how to get a odd degree on $\mathbb P^2$. Can someone help me understand my mistake?

Comment: If your quadratic form $q$ is in $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathcal{E})(k)$, it corresponds to a bilinear form $\mathcal{E}^*\rightarrow \mathcal{E}(k)$, whose determinant is in $\det(\mathcal{E})^{\otimes 2}(3k)$. Hence the degree of the discriminant curve is  $2c_1(\mathcal{E})+3k$.